# joomla2.5.4 new template installation

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

Found `"Fatal error: Call to a member function setDebug() on a non-object in Z:\home\xxx\www\libraries\joomla\installer\adapters\template.php on line 543"` through the installation of a new template via discovering in joomla 2.5.4.

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, it is known bug.

Sources :
http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_id=8103&tracker_item_id=28345

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=619&t=708286#p2784057

Answer (score 2):

This problem arises because of missing function call in function `discover_install()` in 
libraries\joomla\installer\adapters\template.php:
`$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();`

Add this line to this file and stuff will be working ;)

Cheers
/Dzenan

Comment: Line 503 for anyone interested.

Answer (score 1):

Dzenan's solution worked for me. I added...

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
```

...to line 480 in libraries\joomla\installer\adapters\template.php and the template installed during the discover/install process.

Comment: According to here http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_id=8103&tracker_item_id=28345 it is line 503.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Joomla 2.5.4 and as per the bug tracker mentioned by Stu I added.

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
```

But I added it to the function starting on line 503 of the file

libraries\joomla\installer\adapters\template.php

```
public function discover_install()
    {
        // Templates are one of the easiest
        // If its not in the extensions table we just add it
        $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
        $client = JApplicationHelper::getClientInfo($this->parent->extension->client_id);
```

This worked like a charm.
Thanks Stu & Dzenan

Bug tracker link
http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_id=8103&tracker_item_id=28345